# Can not implement ExtJs 5 side navigation tabs from example

Tags: javascript, navigation, extjs5, tabpanel

Had anyone managed to embed this [example](http://dev.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/examples/kitchensink/#side-navigation-tabs) locally?

When I try to do the same in my local project only right part of tabs are visible other left part is hidden. I use iconCls not glyph.

I think problem is that I couldn't compile this properly

```
@include extjs-tab-panel-ui(
    $ui: 'navigation',
    $ui-tab-background-color: transparent,
    $ui-tab-background-color-over: #505050,
    $ui-tab-background-color-active: #303030,
    $ui-tab-background-gradient: 'none',
    $ui-tab-background-gradient-over: 'none',
    $ui-tab-background-gradient-active: 'none',
    $ui-tab-color: #acacac,
    $ui-tab-color-over: #c4c4c4,
    $ui-tab-color-active: #fff,
    $ui-tab-glyph-color: #acacac,
    $ui-tab-glyph-color-over: #c4c4c4,
    $ui-tab-glyph-color-active: #fff,
    $ui-tab-glyph-opacity: 1,
    $ui-tab-border-radius: 0,
    $ui-tab-border-width: 0,
    $ui-tab-inner-border-width: 0,
    $ui-tab-padding: 24px,
    $ui-tab-margin: 0,
    $ui-tab-font-size: 15px,
    $ui-tab-font-size-over: 15px,
    $ui-tab-font-size-active: 15px,
    $ui-tab-line-height: 19px,
    $ui-tab-font-weight: bold,
    $ui-tab-font-weight-over: bold,
    $ui-tab-font-weight-active: bold,
    $ui-tab-icon-width: 24px,
    $ui-tab-icon-height: 24px,
    $ui-bar-background-color: #404040,
    $ui-bar-background-gradient: 'none',
    $ui-bar-padding: 0,
    $ui-strip-height: 0
);
```

How to add this script inside extjs theme and compile? Maybe theme rebuild is nedeed?

Comment: I was having same issue. I just removed "ui: 'navigation'," line. and it worked. Try that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not an expert in ExtJS. I am learning ExtJS 5 to implement it in one of my projects. I am able to get the side navigation panel working under my setup. Steps:

- Create an app using senchacmd (with app generate option).
- Start the server with senchacmd watch command.
- Create a view "NavigationTabs" in app/view/tab/ directory with name "NavigationTabs.js" and place the code below:

  ```
  Ext.define('MyProject.view.tab.NavigationTabs', {
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    xtype: 'navigation-tabs',

    //<example>
    exampleTitle: 'Navigation Tabs',
    otherContent: [{
      type: 'Styles',
      path: 'sass/src/view/tab/NavigationTabs.scss'
    }],
    //</example>

    height: 400,
    width: 600,


    ui: 'navigation',
    tabPosition: 'left',
    tabRotation: 0,
    tabBar: {
      layout: {
          pack: 'center'
      },
      border: false
    },

    defaults: {
      iconAlign: 'top',
      bodyPadding: 15
    },

    items: [{
      title: 'Home',
      glyph: 72,
      html: "Some text"
    }, {
      title: 'Users',
      glyph: 117,
      html: "Some other text"
    }, {
      title: 'Groups',
      glyph: 85,
      html: "Some more text"
    }, {
      title: 'Settings',
      glyph: 42,
      html: "Extra text"
    }]
  });
  ```
- Now, in the sass/src/view/tab/ directory create a file, named : NavigationTabs.scss and place your sass code (you specified in the question) in this file.
- In your Main.js file, present in the app/view/main/ directory, include the following, in the items list:

  ```
  items: [
  {
    ...
    ...
  },
  {
    region: 'west',
    xtype: 'navigation-tabs',
    reference: 'navigation'
  }],
  ```
- Wait for the app and scss to compile (sencha-cmd watch command automatically compiles your code).
- Refresh your app in browser and check if this works.

Hope, this will be useful.

NOTE: The above code is taken from ExtJS5 Kitchen Sink example.